# ¿Porqué no se desactiva la clase active en los demas elementos al dar click?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Quisiera me ayudaran a solucionar ya que he probado varios códigos JavaScript y no me han dado resultado para que solo quede activo el link en el que estoy y al darle click a otro se desactive el anterior y se active el actual.

Gracias de antemano

```js
$('ul.dropdown-menu > li a').on('click', function() {
  // Eliminando clases activas en todos los menus 
  $('ul.dropdown-menu > li').removeClass('active');
  // Añado clase en el li que se ha hecho click
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="nave">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#accountinfo">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ubnaccount">My Urbidnow Account</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bidhist">My Automatic Bid History</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#points">My Points</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#auctions">My Auctions History</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orders">My Orders</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#coupons">My Coupons</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#withdrawals">My Withdrawals</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edité tu snippet y funciona!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas haciendo uso de `jQuery` antes de cargarlo, el resto está bien!

Si colocas tu script al final, luego de la carga de los `cdn`, va a funcionar correctamente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="nave">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#accountinfo">My Profile</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ubnaccount">My Urbidnow Account</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bidhist">My Automatic Bid History</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#points">My Points</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#auctions">My Auctions History</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orders">My Orders</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#coupons">My Coupons</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#withdrawals">My Withdrawals</a></li> 
                 </ul> 
                 </div>
                 </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js'></script>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script>
  $('ul.dropdown-menu > li a').on('click', function() {
  // Eliminando clases activas en todos los menus 
  $('ul.dropdown-menu > li').removeClass('active');
    // Añado clase en el li que se ha hecho click
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

});</script>
```

Saludos!

Comment: hola es cierto ahora el problema es el siguiente, tengo un tab debajo que carga informacion pero ahora cada link no abre su tab. te dejo el codigo...

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta aparte, da este tema por cerrado, e inicia una nueva pregunta para que se te ayude, de otra manera, sólo te sería útil a ti y no es lo que se persigue en StackOverflow

Comment: ok, asi lo hare. soy nuevo y no lo sabia!! Gracias!

Comment: No hay problema! Si está respuesta fue la que solucionó tu problema te pido que toques el tick que tenes a tu izquierda. Para que esta pregunta se dé por solucionada, Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

este es el codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>User Detail Panel</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style type="text/css">
    body {background: #EAEAEA;}
.iconsize {font-size: 20px!important;}
.user-details {position: relative; padding: 0;}
.user-details .user-image {position: relative;  z-index: 1; width: 100%; text-align: center;}
 .user-image img { clear: both; margin: auto; position: relative;}

.user-details .user-info-block {width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 55px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 0; padding-top: 35px;}
 .user-info-block .user-heading {width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 0;}
 .user-info-block .navigation {float: left; width: 100%;  padding: 0; list-style: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #428BCA; border-top: 1px solid #428BCA;}
  .navigation {margin-top: 40px; }
  .navigation li:first-child {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   .navigation li a:first-child {padding: 20px 59.25px; float: left;}
   .navigation li.active a:first-child {background: #428BCA; color: #fff;}
 .user-info-block .user-body {float: left; padding:5px; width: 90%;}
  .user-body .tab-content > div {float: left; width: 100%;}
  .user-body .tab-content h4 {width: 100%; margin: 10px 0; color: #333; text-align: right;}

  /* Tooltip */
   .test + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
       background-color: #EF7F1A; 
       color: #FFFFFF; 
       border: 1px #EF7F1A; 
       padding: 8px;
       font-size: 15px;
   }
    .caja  {
       border-radius: 10px;
       border: 1px solid #EF7F1A;
       width: 100%;
       height: 400px;
       padding: 20px;

   }

 table.table-content {
     min-width: 50%;
     max-width: 70%;
     margin: 20px;
   }
   table.table-content tr:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: #f4f4f4;
   }
   table.table-content tr th,
   table.table-content tr td {
     padding: 5px 10px 5px  5px;
     font-family: 'Segoe UI';
     color: #555;
   }
   table.table-content tr th {
     padding-left: 10px;
     width: 120px;
   }
   table.table-content tr td {
     word-wrap: break-word;
   }
  .pepito ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 40%;
     box-sizing: content-box;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
     margin-right: 4px;
     clear: right;
     font-size: 12px;
   }
  .pepito ul li span {
     color: white;
     display: block;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     color: #444;
   }
  .pepito ul li span:first-child {
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #45c5ff;
   }
   html,
   body {
     height: 100vh;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     box-sizing: content-box;
   }


   .profile-container {
     background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fdfbfb 0%, #ebedee 100%);
     height: calc(100vh - 65px);
     box-sizing: content-box;
     overflow: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     padding: 0;
   }
   .profile-container .profile-content,
   .profile-container .profile-header {
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #fff;
   }
   .profile-container .profile-header {
     text-align: center;
   }
   .profile-container .profile-header .image {
     padding: 20px;
     height: 150px;
     border: 4px solid #fff;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #fdfbfb 0%, #f7f7f7 100%);
   }
   .profile-container .profile-header .image img {
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
   .dropdown {display: none;  }
   .nave {max-width: 100%;  }

   @media (max-width: 960px) {
  .nave ul:first-child  { display: none; }
  .dropdown{ display: inline-block; }
}
    </style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 user-details">
            <div class="user-image">
                <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2ab7b2009d27ec37bffee791819" alt="Nelson" title="Nelson" class="img-circle">
            </div>
            <div class="user-info-block">
                <div class="user-heading">
                    <h3>Nelson Gutierrez</h3>
                    <span class="help-block">Margarita, VE</span>
                </div>
                <div class="nave">
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My Profile" data-toggle="tab" href="#accountinfo">
                            <span class="iconsize fa fa-user"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My Urbidnow Account" data-toggle="tab"  href="#ubnaccount">
                            <span class="iconsize fa fa-users"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My Automatic bid use history" data-toggle="tab"  href="#bidhist">
                            <span class="iconsize fas fa-magic"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My points" data-toggle="tab"  href="#points">
                            <span class="iconsize fas fa-coins"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My Auctions history" data-toggle="tab"  href="#auctions">
                            <span class="iconsize far fa-calendar-alt"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My Orders" data-toggle="tab"  href="#orders">
                            <span class="iconsize fas fa-tasks"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My coupons" data-toggle="tab" href="#coupons">
                            <span class="iconsize fas fa-ticket-alt"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li>
                        <a class="test" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="My withdrawals" data-toggle="tab"  href="#withdrawals">
                            <span class="iconsize far fa-money-bill-alt"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#accountinfo">My Profile</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ubnaccount">My Urbidnow Account</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bidhist">My Automatic Bid History</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#points">My Points</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#auctions">My Auctions History</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orders">My Orders</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#coupons">My Coupons</a></li> 
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#withdrawals">My Withdrawals</a></li> 
                 </ul> 
                 </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="user-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="accountinfo" class="tab-pane active">
                            <h4>Account Information</h4>
                           <div>
                             <div>
                               <section class="profile-container row">
                                 <div class="profile-header col m3 s12">
                                   <div class="image">
                                     <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" alt="" />
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="profile-information">

                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="profile-content col m9 s12">

                                   <table class="table-content">
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Card ID</th><td>125465</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Title</th><td>Le Card Title</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Requestor</th><td>John Doe</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Kab</th><td>Le Kab</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Board</th><td>Board X</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Assignee</th><td>Jane</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <th>Stage</th><td>Completed</td>
                                     </tr>
                                   </table>
                                    <div class="pepito">
                                   <ul>
                                   <li>
                                       <span>Card ID</span><span>125465</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Title</span><span>Le Card Title</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Requestor</span><span>John Doe</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Kab</span><span>Le Kab</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Board</span><span>Board X</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Assignee</span><span>Jane</span>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                       <span>Stage</span><span>Completed</span>
                                     </li>
                                   </ul></div>
                                 </div>
                               </section>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ubnaccount" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Urbidnow Account</h4>
                            <div>
                              <div>
                                <section class="profile-container row">
                                  <div class="profile-header col m3 s12">
                                    <div class="image">
                                      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-information">

                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="profile-content col m9 s12">

                                    <table class="table-content">
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Card ID</th><td>125465</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Title</th><td>Le Card Title</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Requestor</th><td>John Doe</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Kab</th><td>Le Kab</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Board</th><td>Board X</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Assignee</th><td>Jane</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Stage</th><td>Completed</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                     <div class="pepito">
                                    <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>Card ID</span><span>125465</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Title</span><span>Le Card Title</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Requestor</span><span>John Doe</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Kab</span><span>Le Kab</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Board</span><span>Board X</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Assignee</span><span>Jane</span>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <span>Stage</span><span>Completed</span>
                                      </li>
                                    </ul></div>
                                  </div>
                                </section>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bidhist" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Automatic Bid History</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="points" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Points</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="auctions" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Auctions History</h4>
                        </div><div id="orders" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Orders</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="coupons" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Coupons</h4>
                        </div><div id="withdrawals" class="tab-pane">
                            <h4>My Withdrawals</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});

</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js'></script>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
  $('ul.dropdown-menu > li a').on('click', function() {
  // Eliminando clases activas en todos los menus 
  $('ul.dropdown-menu > li').removeClass('active');
    // Añado clase en el li que se ha hecho click
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Llévalo a otra pregunta por favor.